# Get latest information from inventdim having transactionid D365

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax7

can someone show me a easy way to get information from inventdim? I need to get batchid/ siteid/locationid for a project transaction. D365FO
I tried this select but I don't think its accurate enough

> ```
> while select InventTransOrigin join salesline where SalesLine.InventTransId == InventTransOrigin.InventTransId
>         &&  SalesLine.inventtransid == ProjItemTrans::find(projInvoiceItem.ProjTransId).inventtransid
>        join inventTrans where InventTrans.InventTransOrigin == InventTransOrigin.RecId
>        join inventdim order by inventdim.inventBatchId desc where InventDim.inventDimId == InventTrans.inventDimId
> ```

Comment: Why do you think it is not accurate enough? Also, the join with `SalesLine` is unnecessary, you could join `InventTransOrigin` directly with `ProjItemTrans`.

Comment: When I did run this query in sql workbench i got like 100000 records for one transid but they had different batchid's

Comment: Hm, agreed, that does not seem right. I noticed that `ProjItemTrans` also has an `InventDimId` field, why don't you use that?

Comment: Well when I tried to connect it thay way I don't get any batchid. I debugged it and no value for bachid is shown but for siteid and locationid its ok.

tmpPSAProjInvoice.inventsite = inventdim::find(projitemtrans::find(projInvoiceItem.projtransid).InventDimId).Inventsiteid